# How to compare 2 time on blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

in my app , I used DateField to get  future time and i save the time as string like as **1 Feb 2012 23:49** to make a schedule for work. And I want to compare this time with time current. If **time schedule** = **time current** + 4 hour, a dialog will appear to remind working.
But compare 2 times is so difficult . Because it depend on some cases example AM or PM, or if time schedule is **2 Feb 01:00 AM**  and time current is **1 Feb 21:00 PM** , dialog also display.

Can anybody help me compare full correctly if time schedule = time current + 4 hours ?

Comment: How are you comparing the times? Do you parse the strings back into date objects?

Comment: please explain one thing do you want to compare two times?\

Comment: I use DateField for the user take the time in the future. I save this time as string (use method dateField.toString() ). And when this time is saved. My app always check the time current use clockUpdated(). If time current + 4 hours = time saved, run an dialog. But some case compare difficultly example when time saved is begin day of the month( example Feb) and time current is end day of January... I want to compare correctly for all cases.

Comment: can DateField save with DayWeek ? example **Sat** 2 Fed 02:00 PM? I think use DayWeek more easily to compare

Comment: simple try to convert  date or time or date and time what is it maybe  into milliseconds and compare that with current time  in milliseconds.you can achieve  your requirement easily. if you need any example for that let me know i will prepare for you,give me reply fast

Comment: @HelpMeToHelpYou yes, i need your helping with example. Sorry for late replying

Comment: k i will prepare and i will give you.

Comment: yes, i am waiting, you are frienly :)

Comment: see my answer if you have more doubts please come here i will help you http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpDateParser;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class StartUp extends UiApplication {
    /**
     * Entry point for application
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         StartUp start=new StartUp();
         start.enterEventDispatcher();

     }
    /**
     * Creates a new StartUp object
     */
    public StartUp() {
        // Push a screen onto the UI stack to have something to render before we attempt

        pushScreen(new DateComparision());



    }
    class DateComparision extends MainScreen
    {
        public DateComparision() 
        {
            String first="31 Jan 2012 23:49:01";//formate should same 
            long time1=HttpDateParser.parse(first)+(4*60*60*1000);//means after 4 hours 
            //time1= 1328068141000
            String second="1 Feb 2012 03:49:01";
            long time2=HttpDateParser.parse(second);
            //time2=1328068141000
            System.out.println(time2+"  "+time1);
            if(time2==time1){
                displayMessage("Mached");
            }else 
            {
                displayMessage("Not Mached");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void displayMessage(final String data){
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.inform(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save time in same Format means like this one **1 Feb 2012 23:49** and the second time you want to compare if it is in Am or Pm change that to 24 hrs format. And compare or convert Date to String and compare the String. If both String are equal then do your Task.

Comment: I did that but it not full correctly for some cases about end day of current month and begin day of the next month.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'normalize' date: use Unix timestamp as returned by java.util.date.

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html Use Unix time to do maths (as add and subtract) on dates, and use date format as 2 Feb 2012 09:00 just for the user presentation.